# Updating a field using Ecto one-liner?

Tags: elixir, ecto

In Ruby, I can go:

```
User.find_by(email: "foobar@email.com").update(email: "hello@email.com")
```

How can I do something similar in Elixir?

```
Ecto.Changeset.change(MyApp.User |> where(email: "foobar"), email: "barbaz") |> MyApp.Repo.update
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
from(u in MyApp.User, where: u.email == "sergio@email.com") |> MyApp.Repo.update_all(set: [email: "sergiox@email.com"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set:` in a query and run it using `Repo.update_all/1`:

```
from(
  u in User,
  where: u.email == "foobar@email.com",
  update: [set: [email: "hello@email.com"]]
) |> Repo.update_all([])
```

Comment: `(Ecto.Query.CompileError) unsupported :set in keyword query expression`

Comment: @SergioTapia oops, forgot to put `update: []` around the `set:`. Could you try my updated answer?

Comment: I get this now: `** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Stitch.Repo.update_all/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:`

Comment: I should have tried the code before posting... Does `|> Repo.update_all([])` work?

Comment: Check out my answer I used your from query and piped it into the update_all/2

Comment: Yep, my answer should work as well. `update` can be put either in the query or passed to `update_all`.